# Python: writing a JSON string to a file.

Tags: python, json, encoding

I have a custom object that I have serialized into `JSON` data. After the serialization, I write the data back to a `JSON` file. This seems to be working, however the JSON that I write back to a file is now a string (i.e. it starts with a `"` and ends with a `"`).

So when I try to load the new file into be parsed, my parser things that it's a string and I get the error:

```
 TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I serialize the object by doing:

```
class myEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return o.__dict__
```

and then calling this class:

```
with open('updatedMapData.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(myEncoder().encode(jsonToEncode) , outfile)
```

`myEncoder().encode(data)` returns perfectly, but when it writes, the file is a long string.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please include some sample input and output?

Comment: Looks like you encode it (which returns a JSON string) and then put it into `dump`, which encodes it again, and since it was a JSON string already you get JSON inside a JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
outfile.write(myEncoder().encode(jsonToEncode))
```

Answer (score 0):

json.dump's first argument is the object that you want to convert to JSON, but you can pass your class as the `cls` argument, so you need to call it like this:

```
json.dump(jsonToEncode, outfile, cls=myEncoder)
```